# how to pass value from recyclerview to a fragment using interfaces in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an application to debate, for this I use java and xml. The application shows a list with the arguments that users add about a topic published in the app. When a user wants to argue, he clicks on an image view which displays an alertdialog asking if he really wants to counter. So far everything works perfectly, the problem comes when the user presses 'ok I want to counter' (button inside the alert dialog), since when doing that it returns the following error: "java .lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void Fragments.sendArgument.sendArgument(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference". I should send the argument as a parameter to another fragment to be displayed there in this new fragment. I am using interfaces to send the variable that stores the argument to another fragment. I leave you part of my code so that you can help me. Greetings

recyclerview

```
public class adapterArguments extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterArguments.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ListArguments> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public String position_selected,argument;
    public static String argument_aux;
    private sendArgument sendArgument;



    public adapterArguments(List<ListArguments> itemList, Context context,sendArgument argument) {
        this.data = itemList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.sendArgument = argument;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compontents_arguments_recyclerview,null);
        return new adapterArguments.ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.arguments.setText(data.get(position).getArguments());
        holder.name_user.setText(data.get(position).getName_user());
        holder.date.setText(data.get(position).getDate_arguments());
        holder.position.setText(data.get(position).getPosition());
        position_selected = holder.position.getText().toString();
        if(position_selected.equals("A favor")){
            holder.position.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#073FD7"));
        }
        else{
            holder.position.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FC0C1E"));
        }
        holder.addContrarguments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Añadir un Contrargumento");
                alertDialog.setMessage("¿Quieres añadir un contrargumento a este texto?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                argument = holder.arguments.getText().toString();
                                sendArgument.sendArgument(argument);
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager;
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
                                fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new contrargument());
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog customAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
                customAlertDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView arguments,name_user,date,position;
        ImageButton addContrarguments;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            arguments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arguments_posted);
            name_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_arguments);
```

adapter

```
package Fragments;

public interface sendArgument {
    void sendArgument (String Argument);
}
```

fragment

```
public class contrargument extends Fragment implements sendArgument {
    public String name_user_post_argument,argument_posted;
    TextView text_contrarguent,argument,valoration_argument;
    Button post_contrargument;
    ImageView increace_valoration,decreace_valoration,back_fragment;
    public int valoration;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contrargument, container, false);
       argument = view.findViewById(R.id.text_argument);
       text_contrarguent = view.findViewById(R.id.contrargument_post);
       post_contrargument = view.findViewById(R.id.post_contrargumment);
       name_user_post_argument = perfil_user.name_aux;
       increace_valoration = view.findViewById(R.id.increace_valoration);
       decreace_valoration = view.findViewById(R.id.decreace_valoration);
       valoration_argument = view.findViewById(R.id.valoration_argument);
       back_fragment = view.findViewById(R.id.returned);
       valoration = 0;

       increace_valoration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                valoration = valoration + 1;
                valoration_argument.setText(String.valueOf(valoration));
            }
        });
        decreace_valoration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(valoration > 0){
                    valoration =   valoration - 1;
                    valoration_argument.setText(String.valueOf(valoration));
                }
                else if (valoration == 0 ){
                    valoration_argument.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                }
                else{
                    //pass
                }
            }
        });

       return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendArgument(String Argument) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got: " + Argument, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need interface. you can directly pass the data to your fragment like this.

```
    contrargument fragment = new contrargument()
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("argument", data.get(position).getArguments());
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
```

inside your contrargument, get the sent argument inside onViewCreated of your fragment.

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String argument = args.getString("argument");
```